# How do I split a string by commas except inside parenthesis, using a regular expression?

Tags: ruby, regex

I want to split a string by comma:

```
"a,s".split ','  # => ['a', 's']
```

I don't want to split a sub-string if it is wrapped by parenthesis:

```
"a,s(d,f),g,h"
```

should yield:

```
['a', 's(d,f)', 'g', 'h']
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To deal with nested parenthesis, you can use:

```
txt = "a,s(d,f(4,5)),g,h"
pattern = Regexp.new('((?:[^,(]+|(\((?>[^()]+|\g<-1>)*\)))+)')
puts txt.scan(pattern).map &:first
```

pattern details:

```
(                        # first capturing group
    (?:                  # open a non capturing group
        [^,(]+           # all characters except , and (
      |                  # or
        (                # open the second capturing group
           \(            # (
            (?>          # open an atomic group
                [^()]+   # all characters except parenthesis
              |          # OR
                \g<-1>   # the last capturing group (you can also write \g<2>)
            )*           # close the atomic group
            \)           # )
        )                # close the second capturing group
    )+                   # close the non-capturing group and repeat it
)                        # close the first capturing group
```

The second capturing group describe the nested parenthesis that can contain characters that are not parenthesis or the capturing group itself. It's a recursive pattern.

Inside the pattern, you can refer to a capture group with his number (`\g<2>` for the second capturing group) or with his relative position (`\g<-1>` the first on the left from the current position in the pattern)  *(or with his name if you use named capturing groups)*

Notice: You can allow single parenthesis if you add `|[()]` before the end of the non-capturing group. Then `a,b(,c` will give you `['a', 'b(', 'c']`

Comment: `txt.scan(pattern).map &:first` solved the problem. @casimir really I can't double up-vote your answer, thanks!

Comment: I was curious about -1 in regexp. can you please also explain this part `<-1>`

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that parentheses are not nested:

```
"a,s(d,f),g,h"
.scan(/(?:\([^()]*\)|[^,])+/)
# => ["a", "s(d,f)", "g", "h"]
```

Comment: thanks for edits & awesome answer! one issue though, this will not cater nested parentheses 
`"a,s(d,f(4,5)),g,h".scan /(?:\([^()]*\)|[^,])+/` => `["a", "s(d", "f(4,5))", "g", "h"]`

Comment: "a,s(d,f(4,5)),g,h" should break in ['a', 's(d,f(4,5)', 'g','h']

Comment: It is not an issue. That is expected, as I wrote in the answer. The fact is that your example didn't fully specify nested cases, and I assumed what you didn't wanted.