# Regex, separate by comma, javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

My string:

```
AA,$,DESCRIPTION(Sink, clinical),$
```

Wanted matches:

```
AA
$
DESCRIPTION(Sink, clinical)
$
```

My regex sofar:

```
\+d|[\w$:0-9`<>=&;?\|\!\#\+\%\-\s\*\(\)\.ÅÄÖåäö]+
```

This gives

```
AA
$
DESCRIPTION(Sink
clinical)
```

I want to keep matches between `()`

https://regex101.com/r/MqFUmk/3

Comment: Please verify the string in the example! The desired output makes no sense!

Comment: Oops. Sorry. Fixed!

Comment: How many levels of parenthesis there could be? Could the string be like this: `$, gg(ee(), yy), ee`?

Comment: Maybe this with parenthesis instead could help http://stackoverflow.com/a/18147076/340760

Comment: @BrunoLM That's a nice link, though I'd like to point out that the delimiters are commas, and the secondary delimiters are quotes (which OP could replace with parentheses... maybe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my attempt at the regex

```
\+d|[\w$:0-9`<>=&;?\|\!\#\+\%\-\s\*\.ÅÄÖåäö]+(\(.+\))?
```

I removed the parentheses from within the `[` `]` characters, and allowed capture elsewhere. It seems to satisfy the regex101 link you posted.

Depending on how arbitrary your input is, this regex might not be suitable for more complex strings.

[Alternatively, here's an answer which could be more robust than mine, but may only work in Ruby.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18424315/how-do-i-split-a-string-by-commas-except-inside-parenthesis-using-a-regular-exp)

```
((?>[^,(]+|(\((?>[^()]+|\g<-1>)*\)))+)
```

Comment: Problem is if you add another ending parenthesis, it matches from the first parenthesis to the last one.
I would suggest replacing the capture group with `(\(.+?\))?`, making the inner parenthesis match lazy. In this case, the problems becomes if you have inner parenthesis such as `(a(b)c)`, which would not be matched correctly.

Answer (score 1):

That one seems to work for me?

```
([^,\(\)]*(?:\([^\(\)]*\))?[^,\(\)]*)(?:,|$)
```

https://regex101.com/r/hLyJm5/2

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would first replace all commas within parentheses `()` with a character that will never occur (in my case I used `@` since I don't see it within your inclusions) and then I would split them by commas to keep it sweet and simple.

```
myStr = "AA,$,DESCRIPTION(Sink, clinical),$";            //Initial string
myStr = myStr.replace(/(\([^,]+),([^\)]+\))/g, "$1@$2"); //Replace , within parentheses with @
myArr = myStr.split(',').map(function(s) { return s.replace('@', ','); }); //Split string on ,
//myArr -> ["AA","$","DESCRIPTION(Sink, clinical)","$"]
```

optionally, if you're using [ES6](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), you can change that last line to:

```
myArr = myStr.split(',').map(s => s.replace('@', ','));  //Yay Arrow Functions!
```

***Note:*** If you have nested parentheses, this answer will need a modification

Answer (score 0):

At last take an aproximation of what you need:

```
\w+(?:\(.*\))|\w+|\$
```

https://regex101.com/r/MqFUmk/4

Comment: Nice and short. Spaces are not included though.

Comment: @PerStröm not includes, you dont need it?

Comment: [a-z\$A-Z]+(?:\(.*\))|[a-z\$A-Z]+ i think is more efficient