# Split a Ruby string by colon (except inside parenthesis) using regex

Tags: ruby, regex

I want to split a string by colon.

This is an example of input:

```
str = "one[two:[three::four][five::six]]:seven:eight[nine:ten]"
```

This is an example of output:

```
array = ["one[two:[three::four][five::six]]", "seven", "eight[nine:ten]"]
```

The **aim** is to understand the *regex* representing the **colon outside parentheses and nested parentheses**.

But there are some constraints:

- The template of regex must be like this: `^(.+)<colon_regex>(.*)<colon_regex>(.*)$`
- The match must be unique, with three groups.

Can you give me a suggestion?

Comment: So, the first constraint means `one:two:three:four` should yield no match, right?

Comment: Thanks Cary. Just edited.

Comment: Wiktor this input str = "one:two:three:four" must produce this output array = ["one", "two", "three", "four"] but with this template ^(.+)<colon_regex>(.*)<colon_regex>(.*)<colon_regex>(.*)$

Comment: Can't you just use a special check after you get all the matches? See http://ideone.com/xOPItz where that constraint is implemented with the `chunk_count`var.

Comment: No. I can't. I need of one-line regex. ... or better.... Puppet needs of one-line regex.

Comment: @BnG Well, it's *impossible*, so you're going to be disappointed. Regex has limits. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133601/can-regular-expressions-be-used-to-match-nested-patterns

Comment: @Wiktor, I usually use /:(?=[^\]]*(?:\[|$))/ to match the colon outside parentheses or nested parentheses. I hoped to combine this regex to get the content of (.*) (iaw template), but so far without success.

Comment: I do not know how to write a regex like this for splitting logic. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133601/can-regular-expressions-be-used-to-match-nested-patterns is not relevant for Ruby regex as it supports recursion.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a very simple regex:

```
SUB_CHAR = 0.chr
  #=> "\x00"
r = /#{SUB_CHAR}/
  #=> /\x00/
```

to be used in `s.split(r)`.

There is of course a catch: you must modify the string you pass to Puppet, (along with the above regex).

```
str = "one[two:[three::four][five::six]]:seven:eight[nine:ten]"

count = 0

idx = str.size.times.with_object([]) do |i,a|
  case str[i]
  when '[' then count += 1
  when ']' then count -= 1
  when ':' then a << i if count.zero?
  end
end
  #=> [33, 39]

s = str.dup
  #=> "one[two:[three::four][five::six]]:seven:eight[nine:ten]"
idx.each { |i| s[i] = SUB_CHAR }
s #=> "one[two:[three::four][five::six]]\u0000seven\u0000eight[nine:ten]"
s.split(r)
  #=> ["one[two:[three::four][five::six]]", "seven", "eight[nine:ten]"]
```

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately I need of regex solution because I will use the ruby regex in the title_patterns method of a Puppet module (that accepts only regex).

Comment: I modified my answer to give you what I believe you need, though a bit klutzy, sometimes you do what you gotta do.

Comment: I don't know Puppet (or Rails generally), so my assumption that both the string and the regex are passed to Puppet may be incorrect.

Comment: Puppet is a software configuration manager that use Ruby to accomplish some features. But in certain cases it imposes constraints.

Comment: BnG, will you be passing both the string and regex to Puppet? If so, would have I have proposed work?

Comment: Yes, I can pass the string and regex only. But I can't override the business logic. So I need of regex... unfortunately. It's too hard to resolve the problem with these constraints. I've  a big headache....

Answer (score 1):

Adapting [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18424594/298607) nested parenthesis regex, you can do:

```
txt="one[two:[three::four][five::six]]:seven:eight[nine:ten]" 
pat=Regexp.new('((?>[^:\[]+|(\[(?>[^\[\]]+|\g<-1>)*\]))+)')
puts txt.scan(pat).map &:first
one[two:[three::four][five::six]]
seven
eight[nine:ten]
```

Comment: ...ehm... Ok. It works. But I can't call map method (Limitation imposed by Puppet title_patterns method) and it parse any sting. Instead your input should be parsed by regex like ^(.+)<colon_regex>(.*)<colon_regex>(.*)$

Comment: @BnG: Without recursion, it is not possible purely with a regex.