# How to split a string that contains a set in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, regex, split

I am new to the forum. I am currently trying to take this string:

```
65101km,Sedan,Manual,18131A,FWD,Used,5.5L/100km,Toyota,camry,SE,{AC,Heated Seats, Heated Mirrors, Keyless Entry},2010
```

and split it in order to get this:

```
65101km
Sedan
Manual
18131A
FWD
Used
5.5L/100km
Toyota
camry
SE
{AC, Heated Seats, Heated Mirrors, Keyless Entry}
2010
```

I have the following regex:

```
data_from_file.split(/[{},]+/)
```

But I am having a hard time keeping the set.

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe this answer will be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42475528/split-a-ruby-string-by-colon-except-inside-parenthesis-using-regex will hel

Comment: In future, please ensure all values in examples are valid Ruby objects. Here that would mean putting the string in quotes and displaying the output as an array of strings (`["65101km", "Sedan",..., "2010"]`). Here your intent is clear, but if your array had been an input every reader who wanted to use it in code would have to convert it to a valid object. Also, it's helpful to assign a variable to all inputs (here just one) in your example (`str = "65101km,..."`), so readers can refer to those variables in answers and comments. In case you didn't know, you can upvote answers you checkmark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
s.scan(/(?:{[^{}]*}|[^,])+/)
```

See the [Rubular](http://rubular.com/r/OHBOqP9oB7) and [Regex.101](https://regex101.com/r/ZXTS3D/1/) demos.

**Pattern details**

- `(?:` - start of a non-capturing group:

  - `{[^{}]*}` - `{`, 0 or more chars other than `{` and `}` and then `}`
- `|` - or

  - `[^,]` - any 1 char other than `,`
- `)+` - repeated 1 or more times.

Comment: Simple and clean!

Comment: This is really nice! Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

```
str = "65101km,Sedan,Manual,18131A,FWD,Used,5.5L/100km,Toyota,camry,SE,{AC,Heated Seats, Heated Mirrors, Keyless Entry},2010"
```

```
r = /
    (?<=\A|,)  # match the beginning of the string or a comma in a positive lookbehind
    (?:        # begin a non-capture group
      {.*?}    # match an open brace followed by any number of characters,
               # lazily, followed by a closed brace
      |        # or
      .*?      # match any number of characters, lazily 
    )          # close non-capture group
    (?=,|\z)   # match a comma or the end of the string in a positive lookahead
    /x         # free-spacing regex definition mode

str.scan r
  #=> ["65101km", "Sedan", "Manual", "18131A", "FWD", "Used", "5.5L/100km", "Toyota",
  #    "camry", "SE", "{AC,Heated Seats, Heated Mirrors, Keyless Entry}", "2010"]
```

Two notes follow. I'll illustrate these with a simpler string.

```
str = "65101km,Sedan,{AC,Heated Seats},2010"
```

**1. `{.*?}` must precede `.*?` in `(?:{.*?}|.*?)`**

If

```
r = /(?<=\A|,)(?:.*?|{.*?})(?=,|\z)/
```

then

```
str.scan r
  #=> ["65101km", "Sedan", "{AC", "Heated Seats}", "2010"]
```

**2. The matches `.*` must be *lazy* (aka *non-greedy*)**

If

```
r = /(?<=\A|,)(?:{.*?}|.*)(?=,|\z)/
```

then

```
str.scan r
  #=> ["65101km,Sedan,{AC,Heated Seats},2010"]
```

If

```
r = /(?<=\A|,)(?:{.*}|.*?)(?=,|\z)/
```

then

```
"65101km,Sedan,{AC,Heated Seats},2010,{starter motor, pneumatic tires}".scan r
  #=> ["65101km", "Sedan", "{AC,Heated Seats},2010,{starter motor, pneumatic tires}"]
```

Comment: Hey Cary, for some reason when I put this on regex101, it doesn't read the 2010 at the end. I thank you for the answer !

Comment: What can I say? Ruby matches `"2010"`. Did you perchance test with a string that contains a space between the last comma and "2010"?

Comment: just tried it out its perfect! Thanks guys. I had put a space like Gary said.