# Split a string by commas but no inside parenthesis

Tags: java, regex

Update:
It's not duplicate with [Regex to match only commas not in parentheses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9030036/regex-to-match-only-commas-not-in-parentheses) because it matches commas in the string, but I want to split the string by commas and not to find the commas

**My Test String**

```
String myString = "x1, x2, x3,  x4, x1(x1, x2,x3,x4)";
```

**My Desired Output**

```
x1
x2
x3
x4
x1(x1, x2,x3,x4)
```

I've just read
[How do I split a string by commas except inside parenthesis, using a regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18424315/how-do-i-split-a-string-by-commas-except-inside-parenthesis-using-a-regular-exp) answer, but when I try to get it to Java error occurs

I try this:

```
String[] parts = myString.split("((?:[^,(]+|(\((?>[^()]+|\g<-1>)*\)))+)");
```

Error: Illegal escape character in string literal

What should I do?

Comment: Java regex does not support recursion.